# Schema Update on Azure: Column name does not exist

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two databases, one on local and the same DB but published on Azure.

For the **local DB** I've made a few changes: **added a one to many relationship** is one of them. The models involve are `Device` and `DigitalSystem`

```
public class Device
{
    [Key]
    public int DeviceID { get; set; }
    //FK
    public int DigitalSystemID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DigitalSystemID")]
    public DigitalSystem DigitalSystems { get; set; }
}

public class DigitalSystem
{
    [Key]
    public int DigitalSystemID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

With this, the table inside the local database is updated and includes the `DigitalSystemID` field.

[image]

However, when I generate the script and try to deploy the schema this error appears:

**Error Message:**

[image]

**Question:**

I don't understand this error since I believe that the column is declared. Can someone help me understand it? How can I deploy this schema update to my DB on Azure?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

This is the structure of the `Device` table on Azure.

[image]

It does not have the `DigitalSystemID` column, but this is what I'm trying to achieve, sync Azure to look like the localDB. This isn't done by updating the schema?

This is the result of 'Data Migration Assistant' when I try to deploy the schema [Notice 5 errors (one is the one I described here)]:

[image]

**Schema comparasion thru Visual Studio:**

I tried to compare the schemas in order to detect the differences. However, the result of the comparasion says **there are no differences**, which makes no sense:

[image]

> No differences detected.

Comment: Can you show the structure of the `Device` table in Azure. It seems like there is no `DigitalSystemID` column in  Azure

Comment: Hello, I'll add what you requested, but I can tell you that indeed there is no `DigitalSystemID` on Azure, only on the localDB, what I try to achieve is to create it on Azure aswell (synchronize Azure to look like the localDB), I don't achieve this thru schema update? Sorry I'm very new

Comment: @SankarRaj Updated!

Comment: See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-migrate-your-sql-server-database

Comment: @SankarRaj Sure, I've followed most of the instructions on that article and used 'Data Migration Assistant'. I tried the Schema Migration. The problem comes when I try to deploy the schema. I'm still don't know how to sync these DB ): Am I missing something?

Comment: The error is about adding the index, show where the column is added to the remote db prior to that in the script perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Azure PaaS SQL DB has certain [limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-paas-vs-sql-server-iaas)
Use [Sql Migration Wizard](https://github.com/twright-msft/azure-content/blob/master/articles/sql-database/sql-database-migration-wizard.md) to Move Tables with schema, This tool will notify if there are any compatibility issues.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using Data Migration Assistant for this task. The error message comes from this software, this is no good either?

Comment: your second link (to download the wizard)  is broken